# Where do I put generator configurations in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to define the following:

```
config.generators.stylesheets = false
config.generators.javascripts = false
config.generators.helper = false
```

But despite reading [Ror's guide on the subject](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration), I don't get where exactly the methods should go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it belongs in `config/application.rb`:

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Lots of stuff

    # Generator configuration
    config.generators do |g|
      g.orm             :active_record
      g.template_engine :erb
      g.test_framework  :test_unit, fixture: false
      g.stylesheets     false
      g.helper          false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. The syntaxfFeels weird though, to set `false` like that without an equal sign.

Comment: That is because eg. `g.helper` is a method and not a hash parameter.